# Remove blank space below empty button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using a `<button>` inside a `<div>`, I've noticed if the button is left with no text, an unexpected white space appears below it.

The fiddle here shows it: https://jsfiddle.net/042pt648/ If you comment out the empty button and try the others, they work fine without a white space below. Upon investigation, it seems the height of the parent div with class `.post-comments` is different when the button is empty. When the white space is visible, the parent div has a height of `25px` while the button has a height of `20px`, causing the space. In the other cases, the height is the same as the button(`20px`) just as expected.

Could someone explain what is causing this?

Here is the snippet in question:

```css
.post-comments {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.comment-div-toggle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comments">
  <button class="comment-div-toggle"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `<button>` is an inline level element. Try this to get rid of the whitespace:

```
button {
  display: block;
}
```

Or:

```
button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```